# Как убрать фон в AlertDialog

Tags: android, анимация

Использую [данную библиотеку](https://github.com/JustZak/DilatingDotsProgressBar) для анимации во время обращения к серверу.

То есть создал **xml файл с анимацией**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.zl.reik.dilatingdotsprogressbar.DilatingDotsProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:color="@color/button_background_stroke"
        android:radius="6dp"
        app:dd_animationDuration="500"
        app:dd_horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        app:dd_numDots="6"
        app:dd_scaleMultiplier="2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Показываю анимацию с помощью `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_animation, container, false);

                builder.setView(view2);

                DilatingDotsProgressBar dotsProgressBar = (DilatingDotsProgressBar)
                        view2.findViewById(R.id.progress);

                dotsProgressBar.showNow();

                mProgressDialog = builder.create();

                mProgressDialog.show();
```

Вроде всё хорошо, но анимация имеет неприятный фон (в данном случае белый)

[image: Диалог с анимацией]

Возможно ли как-то убрать этот белый фон? Или есть пути лучше, чем анимация с помощью `AlertDialog`?

Comment: Что-то не получается, пробовал с помощью `android:background="#00ffffff"` с разными значениями альфа. Ставил как корневому лэйауту диалога, так и самому элементу анимации, не меняется ничего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить `AlertDialog` на обычный `Dialog` и установить для него программно прозрачный фон:

```
Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
alertDialog.show();
```

так же нужно в разметке диалога всем элементам поставить прозрачный фон.

на основе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25174316/7566397)